# How to send data from one page to another and upon success show a modal

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

This is my page from where I want to send data to dashboard/fpass.php page and upon success show a modal.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#fmodal').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "dashboard/fpass.php",
             data: { name: "fpass" }
        })
        success: function(data) {
             $("#myModal").modal();
        }
    }); 
 });            
</script>
```

And here is my next page where I want to get my data and send a mail.

```
<?php 
   if(($_POST['name'])=='fpass')
   {
      /*add sql connection*/
      require('../includes/dbconfig.php');

      /*get the image file name from the table*/
      $sql="select * from admin";
      $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
      $email=$row['email'];
      $password=$row['password'];
      $bemail=$row['bemail'];

      $sub="dashboard login password is < ".$password." >";

      /*send mail to the sql entry*/

      mail($email,"Forget Password Request",$sub,$bemail);
  }
?>
```

Comment: where is your question? what doesn't work? what did you try?

Comment: Corrected the syntax and formatted the code

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code is not valid. Have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp), to see how `$.ajax(...)` is used:

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your AJAX:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fmodal').click(function(){
            var name = 'fpass';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "dashboard/fpass.php",
                data: { name: name },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#myModal").modal('show');
                }      
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, the problem that I see is in the receiving code. AJAX needs to get some response from that file, you are not sending anything back, that's why. When you execute the mail() function, if CORRECT, then return true, 1 or any message that you want referring to the successful operation.
Try this:

```
if (mail($email,"Forget Password Request",$sub,$bemail))
    echo true; //or echo 1, something referring to successful execution
else {
    /**
     * If you want to use the error{} part of the AJAX, you need to send different headers
     * header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
     */
    // And then the echo, or just the echo is fine if you want to use it in the success section

    echo false; // or echo 0, somtehing referring to a failed execution
}
```

In the AJAX side, you get the response, and evaluate if is true or false and then you decide what to do.

Hope that can help. J.C!